# how to make next js read my environment file?

Tags: next.js

I went here to find that using a .env file with PORT=.... will tell next js to change port during serve. But it is always falling back to 3000. I don't want it to be hard coded into my package.json. any hints?

Comment: afaik nextjs doesnt support using port from env file to host

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely don't want it in your `package.json`, then I guess this can be hacked together using the [dotenv-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-cli) package. This way your `.env` file containing the PORT could be loaded into the shell before starting the server. Your scripts in `package.json` could then look like the following:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start:dev": "dotenv -e .env.development next dev",
  "start": "dotenv -e .env.production next start"
}
```

Essentially, the `dotenv` command loads the `.env` file specified by the `-e` option, and takes the rest of positional arguments (e.g., `next dev`) as the command to run using the variables loaded from the file.

Do bear in mind that Next.js also reads `.env` files by itself after starting (it just does it after the port has been claimed and the server has been started). It has some [default paths](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) that can be used to organize them.

Answer (score 0):

**package.json:**

```
"scripts": { 
   "dev": "next dev",
   "start": "next start",
},
```

**Solution**:
Set `PORT` before you start Next.js's server.

**Explanation**: If you put it inside the `.env` file it won't use it since it reads the file AFTER it starts the server.

**Example**: `PORT=8080 npm run dev` or `PORT=80 npm start`.

Hope this helps!